# Extracting .bdf from Matlab generated .set file

Tags: matlab, file-format, european-data-format

Excuse if this is more a file format conversion question rather than programming, but I can't find anyone who can help extract the embedded .bdf (bio signals format) data from this .set file

http://statigrafix.com/temp/EEG-set/Target_1.set

Which seems from the header to have been generated from MATLAB 5.

I've asked colleagues at San Diego Supercomputing Center and CALIT2 but no luck yet. Can someone somewhere in the world figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like an [EEGLAB](http://sccn.ucsd.edu/eeglab/) [dataset](http://sccn.ucsd.edu/eeglab/data/headit.html) file, which is simply a regular MAT-file with a structure variable stored inside. This structure contains various info about the biosignals.

You could manually load the data using LOAD function, or use the [provided GUI](http://sccn.ucsd.edu/wiki/Chapter_01%3a_Loading_Data_in_EEGLAB#Opening_an_existing_dataset) to open the dataset.

```
>> load Target_1.set -mat
>> EEG
EEG = 
             setname: 'Target_1'
            filename: 'Target_1.set'
            filepath: '/home/julie/FiveBox_JO'
             subject: ''
               group: ''
           condition: ''
             session: []
            comments: [1x803 char]
              nbchan: 238
              trials: 1
                pnts: 99129
               srate: 256
                xmin: 0
                xmax: 387.22
               times: []
                data: [238x99129 single]
              icaact: []
             icawinv: [238x238 double]
           icasphere: [238x238 double]
          icaweights: [238x238 double]
         icachansind: [1x238 double]
            chanlocs: [1x238 struct]
          urchanlocs: []
            chaninfo: [1x1 struct]
                 ref: 'common'
               event: [1x616 struct]
             urevent: [1x18879 struct]
    eventdescription: {''  ''  ''  ''}
               epoch: []
    epochdescription: {}
              reject: [1x1 struct]
               stats: [1x1 struct]
            specdata: []
          specicaact: []
          splinefile: ''
       icasplinefile: ''
              dipfit: [1x1 struct]
             history: [1x1022 char]
               saved: 'yes'
                 etc: []
```

Comment: thanks. I use Mathematica, which can import .bdf, and don't have access to Matlab. Is it possible to extract the .bdf without Matlab?

Comment: @alancalvitti: I believe MM is capable of importing MAT-files: [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/MAT.html)

Comment: in MMA8, Import["Target_1.set","MAT"] returns a series of errors of the type: "Partition::ilsmp: "Single or list of positive machine-sized integers expected at position 2 of Partition[{},0]" and Import fails. I've tried not using "MAT" option but can't infer the format.

Comment: @alancalvitti: I'm not sure, but maybe it's choking because of the nested structures... You should ask this on the [Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) website, and link to this question for reference

Comment: If you don't have access to Matlab then you can import .bdf files in R using `edfReader` package

Answer (score 0):

You can add a plug-in of inporting( about BDF) in eeglab, then load your data to eeglab and export as .bdf file. after that you will obtain a .bdf file. But this file can not be uesed still, you need to add file extension as '*.dbf'. Finally, the bdf can be loaded into another software to analysis.